# Android HttpGet is requesting indexAction

Tags: android, zend-framework-mvc, zend-rest

my HttpGet request is calling my indexAction, instead of getAction. What's going on?

Here are my codes:

```
    public function getAction() {

    $id = $this->_getParam('id');

    if(!$id)
    {
        $this->getResponse()
             ->setHttpResponseCode(400)
             ->setBody("no id");
        return;
    }

    try
    {
        $q = Doctrine_Query::create()
             ->from('Milotin_Model_Locations l')
             ->where ('l.id=?', $id);

        $result = $q->fetchArray();

        if(count($result) == 1)
        {
            $this->getResponse()
                 ->setHttpResponseCode(200)
                 ->setBody(json_encode($result));
        }
    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
        $this->getResponse()
             ->setHttpResponseCode(500)
             ->setBody($e->getMessage());
    }
}



    public function indexAction() {
}
```

And here is my code in Android:

```
    private static void getLoc()
{
    final HttpResponse response;

    final HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet(LOCATION_URI + "?geolat=" + geoLat + "&geolong=" + geoLong);

    try {
        response = mHttpClient.execute(getRequest);

        if(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200)
        {
            //do something
        }

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

My HttpPost is working correctly (it calls postAction), Any explanation?

Thanks.

Comment: what are you trying to do exactly? What is the problem exactly? mention it clearly.

Comment: I was trying to call a HttpGet, but it is redirected to indexAction, instead of getAction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. It's actually the behavior of Zend Framework. If the 'id' element is not found in the GET request, it will redirect to indexAction, instead of getAction.

Example:

'GET localhost/student' will redirected to indexAction, while
'GET localhost/student/23' will redirected to getAction. (23 is the id)

Found it in Zend Framework: A beginner's guide, by Vikram Vaswani.